# Xpath contain exact word

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<book>
    <title>Sword of Honour</title>
    <category>foo</category>
    <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
</book>
<book>
    <title>Moby Dick</title>
    <category>foo bar</category>
    <author>Herman Melville</author>
</book>
<book>
    <title>Sayings of the Century</title>
    <category>bar foo</category>
    <author>Nigel Rees</author>
</book>
<book>
    <title>The Lord of the Rings</title>
    <category>bar</category>
    <author>J. R. R. Tolkien</author>
</book>
<book>
    <title>The Lord</title>
    <category>foo,bar</category>
    <author>J. Tolkien</author>
</book>
```

I want to get data where category exactly contains "foo" which would be:

```
<book>
    <title>The Lord</title>
    <category>foo,bar</category>
    <author>J. Tolkien</author>
</book>
<book>
    <title>Sword of Honour</title>
    <category>foo</category>
    <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
</book>
```

when I try :

```
//*[contains(category, "foo")]
```

it returns the following elements :

```
<book>
    <title>Sword of Honour</title>
    <category>foo</category>
    <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
</book>
<book>
    <title>Moby Dick</title>
    <category>foo bar</category>
    <author>Herman Melville</author>
</book>
<book>
    <title>Sayings of the Century</title>
    <category>bar foo</category>
    <author>Nigel Rees</author>
</book>
<book>
    <title>The Lord</title>
    <category>foo,bar</category>
    <author>J. Tolkien</author>
</book>
```

whereas when I try :

```
//*[category="foo"]
```

it returns the following elements :

```
<book>
    <title>Sword of Honour</title>
    <category>foo</category>
    <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
</book>
```

Is there a way that I could get my data. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `//*[category="foo"]` returns 2 books for me

Comment: @splash58 In real I had JSON which has multiple category separated with commas. But I couldn't find a similar question. So I converted it in XML. Would it work if I convert the last one separated with Comma. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Is category list containing spaces after comma ?

Comment: @splash58 Not necessarily. Spaces are optional.

Comment: Xpath will be different with spaces and without

Comment: @splash58 Ok I will make sure there are no spaces.

Comment: The problem with using `contains` here will become more evident once you search for 'fiction' - you'll get 'non-fiction' and 'science fiction' in the mix. I would suggest you fully normalize `<categories><category>cat1</category><category>cat1</category>...</category>` and then do exact string matches, rather than hacking joined data with commas etc.

Comment: @StuartLC The problem is I have to use this for a JSON using defiant.js. It also uses XPath queries to find data from JSON. The JSON has categories separated by commas only. To get exact answer on Stack I converted the JSON to XML as XML XPath is much more popular tag here. Isn't there a way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If category may contain list of item separated by comma:

```
//category[contains(concat(",", ., ","), ",foo,")]/ancestor::book[1]
```

Adding comma before and after is needed to avoid selecting f.e.`thefoos` category while finding `foo`

Comment: This gives an error. To be exact clear I have posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/q/47766348/6755753 . It would be nice if you could help there. I would then close this question