# Searching a JSON with Javascript with exact tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xpath

I have a following JSON where search is to be performed by selecting filters:

```
{
  "Books": [
     {
        "title": "Book 1",
        "binding": "paperback",
        "category": "pop",
        "language": "english",
        "author": "male"
     },
     {
        "title": "Book 2",
        "binding": "hardcover",
        "category": "pop rock,electro pop",
        "language": "french",
        "author": "female"
     },
     {
        "title": "Book 3",
        "binding": "audiobook",
        "category": "soft rock",
        "language": "german",
        "author": "male,female"
     },
     {
        "title": "Book 4",
        "binding": "boxed set",
        "category": "rock,classic rock",
        "language": "english",
        "author": "female,male"
     },
     {
        "title": "Book 5",
        "binding": "paperback",
        "category": "electro pop,rock,classic rock",
        "language": "french",
        "author": "male/female"
     },
     {
        "title": "Book 6",
        "binding": "paperback",
        "category": "rock",
        "language": "french",
        "author": "male"
     }
  ]
}
```

Available Filters are

```
Binding
  -Paperback
  -Hardcover
  -Audiobook
  -Boxed Set

Category
  -Classic Rock
  -Pop
  -Pop Rock
  -Electro Pop
  -Soft Rock
  -Rock

Language
  -German
  -English
  -French

Author
  -Male
  -Female
  -Male/Female
```

I am using [defiant.js](http://defiantjs.com/) to search from JSON. When I use the following query:

```
var thequery = [];
for (var i in searchTags) {
    for (var j = 0; j < searchTags[i].length; j++) {
        thequery.push('contains(' + i + ' ,"' + searchTags[i][j] + '")');   
    }
}
var thequeryString = thequery.join(' and ');
console.log('//*[' + firstqueryString + ']');
return '//*[' + thequeryString + ']';
```

So when I first click at binding filter then the query I get is `//*[contains(binding ,"paperback")]` and when I click for second time the returned query is `//*[contains(binding ,"paperback") and contains(binding ,"boxed set")]` and this then filters results correctly.

But the problem now is if I want to get the Books which has genre `pop` then with the query `//*[contains(category ,"rock")]` I get

1. Book 2
2. Book 3
3. Book 4
4. Book 5
5. Book 6

But in actual only **Book 4**, **Book 5** and **Book 6** has **Rock** category.

The other query I tried is:

```
var thequery = [];
for (var i in searchTags) {
    for (var j = 0; j < searchTags[i].length; j++) {
        if(i == 'author' || i == 'category'){ 
            thequery.push(i + '[contains(.,"' + searchTags[i][j] + ',")] or ' + i + '[contains(.,",' + searchTags[i][j] + '")] or ' + i + '="' + searchTags[i][j] + '"');
        }else{
            thequery.push('contains(' + i + ' ,"' + searchTags[i][j] + '")'); 
        }
    }
}
var thequeryString = thequery.join(' and ');
console.log('//*[' + firstqueryString + ']');
return '//*[' + thequeryString + ']';
```

And the query I get is `//*[category[contains(.,"rock,")] or category[contains(.,", rock")] or category ="rock"]` which returns:

1. Book 2
2. Book 4
3. Book 5
4. Book 6

The nearest I could get is only here.

So, summarising all I have 2 issues:

1. How to filter Books with the exact filter that I have clicked. E.g. If I click Rock then only Books which contains category rock should be returned.
2. If I use `//*[category[contains(.,"rock,")] or category[contains(.,", rock")] or category ="rock"]` and join it with the main **thequeryString** with `and` it doesn't filter out the correct result as the first contains **or**.

Please help.

Note: [defiantjs](http://defiantjs.com/) also has an " XPath Evaluator" where you could check the queries.

Comment: can you please clearly clarify what is the expected output

Comment: I have mentioned it in the question twice. If I click 'Rock' I should only get Book 4, Book 5 and Book 6 as only these three have Rock category. So, I need to filter out the results which exactly has the clicked Tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `forEach` to iterate the array and use `indexOf` to find if the required value is present in that key

```js
var m = {
  "Books": [{
      "title": "Book 1",
      "binding": "paperback",
      "category": "pop",
      "language": "english",
      "author": "male"
    },
    {
      "title": "Book 2",
      "binding": "hardcover",
      "category": "pop rock,electro pop",
      "language": "french",
      "author": "female"
    },
    {
      "title": "Book 3",
      "binding": "audiobook",
      "category": "soft rock",
      "language": "german",
      "author": "male,female"
    },
    {
      "title": "Book 4",
      "binding": "boxed set",
      "category": "rock,classic rock",
      "language": "english",
      "author": "female,male"
    },
    {
      "title": "Book 5",
      "binding": "paperback",
      "category": "electro pop,rock,classic rock",
      "language": "french",
      "author": "male/female"
    },
    {
      "title": "Book 6",
      "binding": "paperback",
      "category": "rock",
      "language": "french",
      "author": "male"
    }
  ]
}




// a function which accepts key which is one of binding,category,language,author.
// the array will be filtered on this key
function getFilteredElement(key, value) {
    var bookFilter = [];
    m.Books.forEach(function(item){
       var getFilterField = item[key];
       // since the value is a string, so splitting it and creating an array
       var keyArray = item[key].split(',');
       // now checking if the passed value has a presence in the  above array
       if (keyArray.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
           // if present pushed the book name
           bookFilter.push(item.title);
       }
   });
    // returning the array of books
    return bookFilter;
}

console.log(getFilteredElement('category', 'rock'))
```

Comment: Thank You this works great, but I need a solution through XPath only as the website has lots of function which is dependent on defiantjs. So I can't use this method.

Comment: it is js inbuild method